# How to create responsive blocks by using just CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css

Check: http://apkapp.in/software/view/43908225?download=ChatAdda.apk

I want to create a responsive block as shown below:

PC View:

[image: PC view]

Mobile View:

[image: Mobile View]

For doing this, I am using the following CSS and HTML:

```css
    <style>
    @media only screen and (min-width:1220px){ #mobile,.mobile{display:none} } 
    @media only screen and (max-width:1220px){ #pc,.pc{display:none} #mobile,.mobile{display:block} } 
    @media handheld{ #pc,.pc{display:none} #mobile,.mobile{display:block} }
    </style>
```

```html
    <div class="pc text">
    <table><tr><td><table><tr><td width="100px"><span class="thumb"><img src="http://img.wapkafile.com/software/thumb/43908225/2696215/935beea5c2c820f5a5e54a65cc7fcc52/240.jpg" /></span></td><td width="*"><h2>ChatAdda</h2>
    <ul><li><strong>Size : 13.11 MB</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Downloads : 12</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Category :<a href="http://apkapp.in/software/list/1430431"> Communication</a></strong></li>
    <li><strong>Price : Free</strong></li>
    </ul></td></tr></table></td>
    <td><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adnetworkperformance.com/a/display.php?r=449076"></script></td></tr></table>
    </div>
    
    <div class="mobile text">
    <table><tr><td width="100px"><span class="thumb"><img src="http://img.wapkafile.com/software/thumb/43908225/2696215/935beea5c2c820f5a5e54a65cc7fcc52/240.jpg" /></span></td><td width="*"><h2>ChatAdda</h2>
    <ul><li><strong>Size : 13.11 MB</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Downloads : 12</strong></li>
    <li><strong>Category :<a href="http://apkapp.in/software/list/1430431"> Communication</a></strong></li>
    <li><strong>Price : Free</strong></li>
    </ul></td></tr></table>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile text"><script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adnetworkperformance.com/a/display.php?r=449076"></script></div>
```

But the issue is that I am using `@media` CSS to show the blocks in mobile and PC views by using `display:none` to the other view which makes me to use the ad code (`<script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adnetworkperformance.com/a/display.php?r=449076"></script>`) for the second block to use two times. How do I display the same using the ad code only once and also without using tables?

Comment: You can use Bootstrap.

Comment: Use bootstrap for this is like kill mosquitos with a rifle

Comment: No. I don't want to use bootstrap. Only CSS and HTML.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Exactly.

Comment: Instead of duplicating the `<div>`s, why not use the `@media` tags to set `display:block` vs `display:inline-block`? This would allow you to arrange them vertically or horizontally depending on screen dimensions, without calling the script resource twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating two div's with the same content for mobile and web views, and hiding / showing one of them with media queries, you should include the content once in html, and change how they are displayed using media queries.

Like;

```
<body>
    <div class="block">
        ... content goes here
    </div>

    <div class="block">
        ... content goes here
    </div>
</body>

<style>
    @media only screen and (min-width:1220px) { 
        .block { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; } 
    } 

    @media only screen and (max-width:1220px) { 
        .block { display: block; }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It worked but the view is bit messed up. Check http://apkapp.in/software/view/43908225?download=ChatAdda.apk again, how do I display them in as in the PC view image above?

Comment: @Macraze you can add vertical-align: middle; have them aligned vertically in pc view. I am updating the answer with that.

Comment: @OzgurAkcali How do I also align it in the center horizontally?

Comment: @Macraze you can try adding text-align: center; to the parent element, and text-align: left; to .block for PC view

Comment: @Ozgur it didn't work. Makes text centered and not the content within the blocks.

Comment: @Macraze what is it you want to center here? If you want make the two blocks centered within their parent in PC view, you should add text-align: center to the parent. This will make the two .block elements centered within the parent, but also the content within the blocks would be centered as well. If you do not want that, add text-align: left; to the .block class. The parent element on your website has the class .text, which is used in other places, too. So in order not to affect other areas, add another class to the parent, say block-parent, and add text-align: center to that class.